# How do I use the WP REST API plugin and the OAuth Server plugin to allow for registration and login?

Tags: api, authentication, wp-api, rest-api, oauth

Are there any example projects that do the same?

I want to be able to login and register for accounts on my site via the API.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit far fetched, but might help. For anyone looking for WP REST API implementation with JWT, here's our solution.

Add it to your function.php

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'wp_rest_user_endpoints');
/**
 * Register a new user
 *
 * @param  WP_REST_Request $request Full details about the request.
 * @return array $args.
 **/
function wp_rest_user_endpoints($request) {
  /**
   * Handle Register User request.
   */
  register_rest_route('wp/v2', 'users/register', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'wc_rest_user_endpoint_handler',
  ));
}
function wc_rest_user_endpoint_handler($request = null) {
  $response = array();
  $parameters = $request->get_json_params();
  $username = sanitize_text_field($parameters['username']);
  $email = sanitize_text_field($parameters['email']);
  $password = sanitize_text_field($parameters['password']);
  // $role = sanitize_text_field($parameters['role']);
  $error = new WP_Error();
  if (empty($username)) {
    $error->add(400, __("Username field 'username' is required.", 'wp-rest-user'), array('status' => 400));
    return $error;
  }
  if (empty($email)) {
    $error->add(401, __("Email field 'email' is required.", 'wp-rest-user'), array('status' => 400));
    return $error;
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    $error->add(404, __("Password field 'password' is required.", 'wp-rest-user'), array('status' => 400));
    return $error;
  }
  // if (empty($role)) {
  //  $role = 'subscriber';
  // } else {
  //     if ($GLOBALS['wp_roles']->is_role($role)) {
  //      // Silence is gold
  //     } else {
  //    $error->add(405, __("Role field 'role' is not a valid. Check your User Roles from Dashboard.", 'wp_rest_user'), array('status' => 400));
  //    return $error;
  //     }
  // }
  $user_id = username_exists($username);
  if (!$user_id && email_exists($email) == false) {
    $user_id = wp_create_user($username, $password, $email);
    if (!is_wp_error($user_id)) {
      // Ger User Meta Data (Sensitive, Password included. DO NOT pass to front end.)
      $user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
      // $user->set_role($role);
      $user->set_role('subscriber');
      // WooCommerce specific code
      if (class_exists('WooCommerce')) {
        $user->set_role('customer');
      }
      // Ger User Data (Non-Sensitive, Pass to front end.)
      $response['code'] = 200;
      $response['message'] = __("User '" . $username . "' Registration was Successful", "wp-rest-user");
    } else {
      return $user_id;
    }
  } else {
    $error->add(406, __("Email already exists, please try 'Reset Password'", 'wp-rest-user'), array('status' => 400));
    return $error;
  }
  return new WP_REST_Response($response, 123);
}
```

IMHO, a more better way would to include the additional function as a seperate plugin. So even when your user changed theme, your api calls won't be affected.

Therefore I've developed a **plugin** for User Registration via REST API in WordPress. Better yet, it supports creating 'customer' for WooCommerce too!

[WP REST User](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-user/), check it out if you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of examples of user registration using the WP REST API and the OAuth server implementation for WP API http://oauth1.wp-api.org/.

I'm sure there were less 6 months ago when you originally posted but here are a couple of great examples that will get you going.

- [Example OAuth Client](https://github.com/WP-API/example-client)
- [WP REST API: Setting Up and Using OAuth 1.0a Authentication](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp-rest-api-setting-up-and-using-oauth-10a-authentication--cms-24797)
- [OAuth Docs](https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1/tree/master/docs)

There are also a few plugins starting to surface.